# Autorun Python script with Pyserial on Startup with Crontab

Tags: python, boot, cron

So I am looking to do something that I thought was simple....

I just have a script that imports and uses pyserial and I want it to run automatically when the pi is booted up. I have an LED rigged up to tell me when the script starts running.

I've gotten the script to run with rc.local, crontab and systemd to turn the LED on, but as soon as I add the "import serial" line into the script, it doesn't want to run anymore. I've even tested it where I turn on the LED, before importing serial and it works, but then the script crashes after that.

What gives?

Any idea what could be causing python to act like this just because I am importing serial?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Soooooo not 5 minutes later I figured out my issue lmao.. I had pyserial installed on my profile, but all of these autorun options run the script as root, so you need to make sure your root account also has these things installed.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Add an answer to others. Thanks.

Comment: ... and please accept your own answer after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years. And yes, you can get upvotes on the answer.